# Conflicting(?) theorems on the Weierstrass Approximation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

I need some help with explaining the differences, and or similarities between these two versions of the Weierstrass Approximation theorem.

On the one hand I have Wikipedia, WolframMathworld and many others stating that the theorem is the following:

- If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $[a, b]$ and if any $\epsilon>0$ is given, then there exists a polynomial $p$ on $[a, b]$ such that
  $$
  |f(x)-P(x)|<\epsilon
  $$
  for all $x \in[a, b]$. In words, any continuous function on a closed and bounded interval can be uniformly approximated on that interval by polynomials to any degree of accuracy.

While in one of my analysis books (Invitation to Classical Analysis by Peter Duren) it is stated as the following:

- Let $q(x)$ be continuous on the interval $[-\pi , \pi ]$, with $q(- \pi)=q(\pi)$. Then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a trigonometric polynomial $T(x)$ such that $|q(x)-T(x)|<\varepsilon$ for $- \pi \leq x \leq \pi $.

Comment: Where is the conflict? These are two different theorems, one with polynomials and the other trigonometric polynomials...

Comment: Conflict in the sense that they are both named the "Weierstrass approximation theorem", while at the same time concerning different functions

Comment: This happens a lot ;) https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_d%27Euler

Comment: Actually both statements can be easily derived from one another; in a sense they are two versions of a same fact.

Comment: We would have a conflict if both claims would contradict each other. This is not the case. Why should a theorem not be allowed to include different types of functions ?